# Undefined refrence to static member variables in C++ 20 shared library only when using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, dll, shared-libraries

I've been migrating my project to use CMake but I've stumbled upon an issue with static member variables. Even when there is a definition for it in the .cpp file.

I've created a minimal reproducable example.

Directory structure:

```
- dll
  - dll.cpp
  - dll.h
- main.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

add_compile_definitions(BUILD)
add_library(sharedLib SHARED dll/dll.cpp dll/dll.h)

link_libraries(sharedLib)
add_executable(exec main.cpp)
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "dll/dll.h"
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    std::cout << A::member << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

dll.cpp

```cpp
#include "dll.h"

int A::member = 10;
```

dll.h

```cpp
#pragma once

#if !defined(BUILD)
#define API __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define API __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

class API A
{
public:
    static int member;
};
```

Comment: Please, show (add to the question post) the **exact error message**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`add_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_definitions.html) command add macros *globally*. For *all* targets. In your example it will be set for both the DLL and the application.

Use [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html#command:target_compile_definitions) instead, to set macros for a single target:

```
# add_compile_definitions(BUILD)
add_library(sharedLib SHARED dll/dll.cpp dll/dll.h)
target_compile_definitions(sharedLib PRIVATE BUILD)
```

---

It's similar with `link_libraries`, it's a global command. Use [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) instead, to set only for a specific target.

Comment: Ahh thanks for the quick anwser. Everything works now.